# How to remove default focus on stepper header in angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper, mat-stepper

I have created a simple application in angular using angular material library in which, I have used dialog component. When dialog is opened by user, it will have stepper component of angular material. It has 3 steps. Every steps has angular reactive forms. Problem that I am facing is that when user open dialog focus is directly done on stepper header's first step. I want to have focus on first form control of reactive form in first step.

```
<mat-form-field class="name">
<input
  matInput
  formControlName="description"
  #name
/>
</mat-form-field>
```

In `component.ts` file, I have written

```
@ViewChild('name', { static: true, read: ElementRef }) name: ElementRef;
```

and in `ngAfterViewInit` method, I have called focus method on name variable like:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.name.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

It works, but output from this I am getting is like it first focus on `FormControl` and then again, move focus to stepper header's first step.
How I should prevent focus from stepper header's first step and keep focus on first `FormControl` ?

Comment: Guess: [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) but provide stackblitz demo if that doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this directive on the element, where the initial focus is expected: `cdkFocusInitial`, if this not enough take a look [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#regions).